# Exception not properly handled in Android intent to uninstall package

Tags: android, android-intent, exception

The following code will uninstall a package on a device if I pass in a package name that exists on the phone.

```
public static String Execute(Context myContext, String packageName){

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
        try{
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
            myContext.startActivity(intent);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("package " + packageName + " not installed");
            return "Package was not uninstalled";
        }

        return "Package " + packageName + " uninstalled.";
    }
```

However if I pass in a package name that isn't on the phone, my exception isn't handled and I get an error that says

> "Invalid packageName or componentName in [packageName]"

[image: stack trace]

and then the return statement "Package [packageName] uninstalled" is returned. What's wrong with my exception handling here? I want the code within the catch statement to be executed/returned if that error occurs, but it's not working.

Comment: Post the actual stack trace, please.

Comment: Are you sure the error you get is an exception? It might just be a printed out string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> my exception isn't handled

That is because it is not an exception and is not coming from your process.

> What's wrong with my exception handling here?

Nothing, other than it not being effective for this case.

Use `PackageManager` to see if the package exists before attempting to delete it.

Comment: I figured it had something to do with that. Thank you.